# Scroll top of the site after releasing wenting down scrollbar

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm coding ajax systeme infinite scroll.
It's working well, I just have A last problem that I can't resolve.

If I scroll down using scrollbar with holding it until ajax is trigger, my screen goes on top

For the moment I do a workaround in order that screen goes where I was before ajax triggered (with var scrollTopSpy), but I don't want display going top, how Can I do to avoid it ?

This my script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {

                    var scrollTopSpy;

                        $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
                            scrollTopSpy = $(window).scrollTop();
                            toastr.warning("chargement en cours...");
                            $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
                        }).ajaxStop(function () {
                            $(window).scrollTop(scrollTopSpy);
                            $("body").css("overflow","auto");
                            toastr.success("chargement terminé");
                        });

                    var page = {{ pager.currentPage }};
                    var lastPage = {{ pager.countTotalPage }};

                    $(window).scroll(function () {
                        $('#more').hide();
                        $('#no-more').hide();
                        $(".pages-btns").hide();

                        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 300) {

                            if (page < lastPage) {  

                                page++;

                                var route = "{{ route("www-place", params|merge({"page":"JSPAGEVAR"})) }}";
                                route = route.replace("JSPAGEVAR", page);

                                $.get( route, function( data ) {
                                    $('.view-list > li:last').after(data);
                                });
                            }
                        }

                    });
                });
                </script>
```

Another information : it's not the ajax call that makes it, but when I went out of $(window).scroll function (I tried return false without success)

This is very simple example with jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gk6df/

So : hold scrollbar, go to extrem down, click on "ok" and see

Comment: so you want to scroll to the top automatically after hitting "ok"? also - you have a weird brightness thing where it keeps asking me to select ok - and the brightness of your site increases with each click...is this something you want?

Comment: No I want to stay bottom, instead of going top after hitting ok (Ajax or hitting ok have same conclusion)

Comment: the way it works for me - it stays at the bottom the way it is.